# as.character() when applied to an individual element of a data.frame vs. the whole 'row' of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c('b','a','c'))
```

If I enter the commands:

`as.character(df$y[1])` or `as.character(df[1,2])`

I end up with the output `"b"`

If I enter the command:

```
as.character(df[1,])
```

I end up with the output `"1" "2"`

I understand that for the final command listed above, R is giving me the factor level of the character 'b'

However, why does it not do that for the first two commands?

What is R actually doing 'internally' when I enter `as.character()`? Whatever it is, I assume it's the reason for the different output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to guide you step by step what my impression is what happens inside R:

### data.frames are actually lists:

```
typeof(df) 
# list

# drops the data.frame class essentially
?`[`
class(df[1, , drop = TRUE])
class(df[1, , drop = FALSE])
```

Since data.frames are actually lists, a line of a data frame is a list with as many elements as there are columns in the data.frame:

```
df[1, , drop = TRUE]
```

### Unlist the list

When you try to coerce a list to a vector, you `unlist()` it. ´unlist()` itself coerces the elements by a certain hirarchy, if not all elements are of the same type. As the **Value** section in the help page of unlist says:

*The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression, after coercion of pairlists to lists.*

### What is my type?

In this case, it has to coerce double and integer values to the highest type, i.e. double. This is because factors are actually stored as integers. Check the code below what happens in which case and with which types we deal:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y = c('b','a','c'))
class(df$x)
typeof(df$x)
class(df$y)
typeof(df$y)
unlist(df[1, , drop = TRUE])
typeof(unlist(df[1, , drop = TRUE]))


df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, # this returns integers
                 y = c('b','a','c'))
class(df$x)
typeof(df$x)
class(df$y)
typeof(df$y)
unlist(df[1, , drop = TRUE])
typeof(unlist(df[1, , drop = TRUE]))
```

As you see, R is coercing all elements in one vector and **then** converts it to character.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help. I understand now why applying as.character() to the coerced vector produces a different result to applying as.character() to a single cell.

Comment: Interestingly, if I use the apply function with margin=1, then 'as.character' gives me a different result (i.e. "1" "b" instead of "1" "2"). I would've presumed that the apply function to a dataframe with margin=1 would coerce each row to a vector as you explained above. Perhaps not.. I will post this as a separate question. Thank you again

Comment: this is because apply() converts the data frame to a matrix via as.matrix(). See the help of as.matrix(): as.matrix is a generic function. The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying as.vector to factors and format to other non-character columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the internals of as.character().
But maybe this fixes the problem:
`df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c('b','a','c'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
Then `as.character(df[1,])` will return `[1] "1" "b"`.
It's  `[1] "1" "b"` and not  `"b"` because df[1,] returns the whole row.

Hope this helps.
Best Regards

Comment: Thank you. The data.frame I gave in the question was just an example. The actual data.frame is much bigger and contains factor columns that I wouldn't want to coerce to character if could avoid it. Thank you though, I appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
> c(as.matrix(df[1,]))
[1] "1" "b"
```

or

```
> mapply(as.character,df[1,])
  x   y 
"1" "b"
```

Comment: thank you, I could coerce to matrix first, that would work.